# .parent() dentro de beforeSend

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $("a.excluiAdmin").click(function() {

        if (confirm('Deseja Excluir este Administrador?') ) {

        var link = $(this);

        $.ajax({
            url: "../_requeridos/excluiAdministrador.php",
            type: 'POST',            
            data : {
                    'administradorid'   : $(this).attr('administradorid')
                   },
            beforeSend: function() {

              $(link).html("<img src='../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif' />")

            },
            success: function (retorno) {

                if (retorno == 1) {

                    alert('Excluido com sucesso');
                    location.reload();

                } else {

                    alert("Erro na exclusão");

                }

            },
            cache: false,
        });

        return false;

      }

  })


});
```

Dentro do `confirm` eu faço:

```
   var link = $(this);
```

Então pego o `this` do **objeto** que sofre a ação;

E no `beforeSend` faço:

```
    beforeSend: function() {

      $(link).html("<img src='../_img/_bannerImgs/spinner.gif' />")

    },
```

Então consigo pegar o `html` do elemento `a` que receberá a ação.

Gostaria de saber se tem como fazer algo do tipo

```
      alert($(this).before($(this)).html())
```

E não depender de fazer

```
var link = $(this);
```

é possível isso?

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente, é necessário utilizar `var algo = $(this);`, devido o escopo da operação.

Quando você acessa o escopo do evento `click()`, e tenta acessar outro escopo, automaticamente o JS vai entender que esse `$(this)` é do escopo atual.

### Exemplos

nessa função, eu preciso definir a variável, para recuperar o objeto do escopo anterior

```
$("div").on("click", function(){
    alert($(this)); //div

    $("div2").on("click", function(){
       alert($(this)); //div2
    });
});
```

Num exemplo mais dinâmico (retirado do Mozilla Developer).

> O valor de this é determinado de acordo com a função chamada.

```
var test = {
  prop: 42,
  func: function() {
    return this.prop;
  },
};

console.log(test.func());
// expected output: 42
```

### Alternativa

Utilizar bind, permitindo  criar uma nova função com o mesmo escopo do objeto original.

```js
function f() {
  return this.a;
}

var g = f.bind({a: 'azerty'});
console.log(g()); // azerty

var h = g.bind({a: 'yoo'}); // bind only works once!
console.log(h()); // azerty

var o = {a: 37, f: f, g: g, h: h};
console.log(o.f(),o.f(), o.g(), o.h()); // 37,37, azerty, azerty
```

### Fontes

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#The_bind_method

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: então do jeito que eu fiz ainda está mais legível e menos código!